# anchor link list show/hide image on mouseover

Tags: jquery, hide, mouseover, show

I trying to make a list of a href with different clients and then add a interaction with the user so it shows different pictures from the clients.

The script do its job but I want to make a little change to it. I want to change the a href so I can link to another page. In this example. When you mouseover client1 it shows a picture from the the client1's website and if you click it should open client1 website in a new tab.

Can i use another .attr in and add it to html code?

I hope someone can help me in here.

Many thanks

```
 <li><a href="#client1">cleint1</a></li>

    </ul></h5>

    <ul id="clientTestimonials">
        <li id="default"></li>
        <li id="client1" class="clients">
            <img src="http://blahblah.com/images/blah2.png">
        </li>
        </li>                       
    </ul>
```

and the jquery..

```
$(document).ready(function() {

       $('#clientTestimonials li').hide();
    $('#clientTestimonials #default').show();

    //attach mouseover events on links
    $('#clientList li a').mouseover(function() {
        // get the classname
        var id = $(this).attr('href');
        $('#clientTestimonials #default').hide();
        $('#clientTestimonials '+id).show();
    });

    $('#clientList li a').mouseout(function() {
        // get the classname
        var id = $(this).attr('href');
        $('#clientTestimonials #default').show();
        $('#clientTestimonials '+id).hide();

    });
});
```

Comment: Could you store the clientID as a data attribute, and then keep the `href` as the URL? Another option would be to create an object which stores the URL as the value, and the key would be the clientID.

Comment: thanks for the reply.. I guess the data attribute idea you mention is the same as the answer underneath? Which doesn't seem to wok for me right away.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `data-client-id` attribute in your links e.g.

```
<ul id="clientList">
   <li><a href="#" data-client-id="client1">cleint1</a></li>
</ul>


<ul id="clientTestimonials">
   <li id="default">default</li>
   <li id="client1" class="clients">new</li>                       
</ul>




  $('#clientTestimonials li').hide();
  $('#default').show();



 $('#clientList li a').mouseover(function() {
    // get the classname
    var cid = $(this).data('client-id');
    $('#default').hide();
    $('#clientTestimonials #'+cid).show();
 });

 $('#clientList li a').mouseout(function() {
    // get the classname
    var cid = $(this).data('client-id');
    $('#clientTestimonials #default').show();
    $('#clientTestimonials #'+cid).hide();

 });
```

UPD: Added out function, I suppose it will work for you now.
**UPD2** Added [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yms55dma/)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I doesn't seem to work right away.. I guess the mouseout part should still be underneath the mouseover code or? It make perfect sense to me but it doesn't hide the default content when I hold the mouse over the client1..

Comment: @Kristian.Johansen Updated my answer. About mouseout part position - it doesn't really matter where you place it, it just has to be defined.

Comment: @Kristian.Johansen UPD2 There is a fiddle, it works fine for me.